# Do I need to put basic modules like OS or Math into a new conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to start using Anaconda the correct way, by making a new environment for each project instead of always using base. I completely reinstalled Anaconda. As far as making my first environment, do I need to specify every module that I want or are the basic ones that come with python (like OS and MATH) included?

Comment: Start a new conda environment with no specific options. Then do a pip freeze and see what packages it has. Usually, environments are for specific tasks. E.g.: for web development you would not normally need keras, but if the necessity arrives, then you just install it.

Comment: So just creating a new environment will add some packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library should be included with all python installs (which also applies to conda environments when you specify python or a python version). [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) you can find what is included in the standard library.

Creating a new environment in conda the following way:

```
conda create --name <name> python=3.x.y
```

or

```
conda create --name <name> python
```

will install python in your environment.

You can reference this nice [cheatsheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) for more conda commands.